# yii2 kartik FileInput - File input empty

Tags: yii2

I am using kartik file input widget in a yii2 project.

http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/fileinput

Everything is fine until the update page is accessed where the already uploaded images for a particular post are displayed using the 'initialPreview' option. The preview works, but when the form is submitted, the file input is empty and the form won't validate. `Poster Image (256x376) cannot be blank.`

```
<?php
     echo $form->field($model, 'posterImage')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
       'options' => [
        'multiple' => true,
        'accept' => 'image/*',
       ],
       'pluginOptions' => [
         'maxImageWidth' => 265,
         'maxImageHeight' => 376,
         'minImageWidth' => 265,
         'minImageHeight' => 376,
         'previewFileType' => 'image',
         'allowedFileExtensions' => [
          'jpg', 'jpeg'
          ],
          'showUpload' => false,
          'maxFileSize' => 200,
          'maxFileCount' => 1,
          'initialPreview' => [
            $model->posterImage ? Html::img($model->posterImage, ['width' => '100%']) : NULL,
           ],
           'initialPreviewConfig' => [
            ['url' => $model->posterImage],
            ],
            'initialPreviewAsData' => false,
            'overwriteInitial' => true,
              ]
                    ]);
                    ?>
```

Comment: can you share your `model` class ?

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the model class(which I can't share). I just want the preview(which works) to be uploaded without having to pick again.

Comment: have you check `skipOnEmpty` on validations rules http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html

Comment: That's a good idea. But I have to integrate it in my design. Let me check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `skipOnEmpty` on yii2 `model` rules with `update` [scenarios](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios)

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['posterImage'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: `[['posterImage'], 'file', 'on' => 'update', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'jpeg, jpg'],` but it doesn't skip it.

Answer (score 2):

@ciprian initialPreview only show image. And not show File input Object for  Upload image. So when you reupload, File object will empty so throw error

Comment: I know, but how do I set the file object?

Comment: @ciprian, you can reference this tutorial for more info. http://webtips.krajee.com/advanced-upload-using-yii2-fileinput-widget/